# Visual C++: Project/linker depends on library which I can't find in the build options

Tags: c++, compiler-construction, linker

In Visual C++, I have a solution and in it a project (made by someone else). I know the dependencies of the project, and so I wrote them in by going to the `Project -> Properties -> Linker -> Input` and inputting the following libraries:

```
../lib/BWAPId.lib
../lib/BWTAd.lib
../lib/tinyxml.lib
../lib/CGAL-vc90-mt-gd.lib
../lib/gmp-vc90-mt-gd.lib
../lib/mpfr-vc90-mt-gd.lib
../lib/libboost_thread-vc90-mt-gd-1_40.lib
```

When I try to build the project however, the following message pops up:

```
fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'libboost_thread-vc100-mt-gd-1_40.lib'
```

Notice the difference: It says the project depends on the "vc100" file, while I know it depends on the "vc90" file. So my question is simply, where could the project possibly have defined that library? I have looked in the "Property Pages" but haven't seen it. Could it be defined in the solution as a whole or something?

Thanks!

Comment: What platform are you compiling with? (Properties -> Platform Toolset), vc90 is AFAIK VS2008, vc100 is VS2010. Also, how do you know it depends on vc90?

Comment: You are using a new compiler version than the one that was used to build Boost libraries. Make sure that both are of equal versions.

Comment: I see that now, and since I do not have 2008 installed I cannot change the option to v90. Perhaps a v100 library can be found elsewhere. I'll search - by the way, if you post an answer, I might mark it correct if this gets fixed.

Comment: AFAIK the new version of BWAPI was updated to VS2010, so you should be fine using vc100 version of libboost. Of course that means you have to build boost with VS2010 for that. *OR* you could install VS2008 express edition. That *should* allow you to pick the vc90 platform toolset within VS2010.

Comment: Have you tried repairing you VS ?

Comment: I see that now. Thanks! Do you know where I can find the sources and/or libraries that I need? GCAL wants me to fill out a questionaire and I'm not even sure it will give the libraries.

Comment: What exactly are you building? I've made BWAPI projects before and I don't remember using the middle libraries.

Comment: BWAPI is now in version 4.0 and no longer "supports" BWTA (a terrain analysis module which uses BWAPI calls to do some fancy stuff). The changes were pretty semantic though, and I managed to recompile BWTA with the latest BWAPI by editing the code. BWTA in turn depends on the libraries above, but the SVN checkout of BWTA yields only the v90 libraries.